# How to get parent comment's id?

Tags: ajax

I am trying to submit comment in Wordpress with Ajax request, but I am struggling with getting the parent comment's id.  Is there any function I can use to get them?

Comment: In what context? When?

Comment: I want to get the parent comment's id in the Ajax handler when I am trying to save comment data passed through $_POST.  How can I do that?

Comment: You need to send the parent comment's ID along with the request.

Comment: But how can I get parent comment's ID with PHP?  If I can get it then I can send it though ```wp_localize_script```

Answer (score -1):

Since you use Ajax, then I would get the current comment from the REST Api, and then [get the parent](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/comments/#schema-parent) from that.

Comment: Could you edit your question with an example of how one may do this?